# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 using Variables

Tags: php, sql

for some odd reason php statement work fine when i only have on item in the array but everytime i add a second one i get an error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" I clearly have the correct column count. please help

$form_array=implode(",",array("james","brown"));

```
$db_array=implode(",",array('firstname','lastname'));
```

$query="INSERT INTO application ($db_array)
                                Value('$array')";

```
$dbquery=mysql_query($query);
if(!$dbquery){
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters or not, but you're calling it `$array` in your query instead of `$form_array`, so maybe it's returning NULL, hence having an incorrect column count.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are not quoted correctly. (and you're using `$array` instead of `$form_array`).
Note `$form_array` after imploding = `'james,brown'`.

Putting that (and `$db_array`) into your query string, you end up with:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO application (firstname, lastname) VALUE ('james,brown');
```

Notice "james" and "brown" are quoted together in a single string - hence column count not matching value count.

You really should use a query string escaping function on your inputs - e.g. [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

Wrote this off the top of my head so might have a minor syntax error somewhere, but the below example should push you in the right direction:

```
$form_array = implode(',', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array('james', 'brown')));
$db_array = implode(',', array('firstname','lastname'));
$query = "INSERT INTO application ($db_array) VALUES ($form_array)";
```

Note you should also take  some more precautions if your `$db_array` is provided by user input in some way.